# Why can $1 + \cos(t+y) + \cos(t+y)(\frac{dy}{dt}) = 0$ be written in the form $(\frac{d}{dt})\lbrack t + \sin(t+y) \rbrack = 0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm reading *Differential Equations and Their Applications* by Martin Braun. In subsection 1.9, which deals with exact equations, the author writes:

> **Example 1.**  The  equation $1 + \cos(t+y) + \cos(t+y)(\frac{dy}{dt}) = 0$ can be written in the form
>   $(\frac{d}{dt})\lbrack t + \sin(t+y) \rbrack = 0$.
>
> Hence, $\phi(t,y) = t + \sin(t+y) = c$, and $y = -t+\arcsin(c-t)$

How do you start with $1 + \cos(t+y) + \cos(t+y)(\frac{dy}{dt}) = 0$ and arrive at $(\frac{d}{dt})\lbrack t + \sin(t+y) \rbrack = 0$?

Comment: Hint: chain rule.

Comment: It follows from the [Chain rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule)

Comment: ... from the chain rule applied to $(\frac{d}{dt})[t+sin(t+y)].$ :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firts note that

$$1+\cos(t+y)+\cos(t+y)\cdot\frac{dy}{dt}=1+\cos(t+y)\cdot\left(1+\frac{dy}{dt}\right)=1+\cos(t+y)\cdot\frac{d}{dt}\left(t+y\right)=\frac{d}{dt}(t)+\cos(t+y)\cdot\frac{d}{dt}\left(t+y\right)$$

by the chain rule: $\cos(t+y)\cdot\frac{d}{dt}\left(t+y\right)=\frac{d}{dt}\sin(t+y)$

$$\frac{d}{dt}(t)+\cos(t+y)\cdot\frac{d}{dt}\left(t+y\right)=\frac{d}{dt}(t)+\frac{d}{dt}\sin(t+y)=\frac{d}{dt}[t+\sin(t+y)]$$